# converting contents of a div into an image

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am creating an image editor type web application. I have a main `div` which will contain many `div` inside it.

When the user clicks on a save button, I want to save the main `div` as an image in a folder.
I tried doing it using `Canvas.toDataURL()` but then I found that i cant place a div(main div) inside canvas tags. I also tried `imagegrabscreen()` function of php but it captured the screen before the whole page is loaded, so it was of no use.

Can anybody help me and suggest a way to implement this using php or javascript?

Comment: imagegrabscreen grabs a screenshot of the server, so i'm guessing you're working on the server itself using http://localhost right ?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a bunch of `div`s when you could just use one `canvas` and draw on it with proper canvas functions?

There are [plenty of examples](http://google.com/search?q=js+canvas+paint+example) of what you're trying to do, such as [this one](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/).

Comment: I dont want to make a paint like thing. I am using a bunch of divs that contain several images and text which the user can edit and then save it as an image.

Comment: Well, you could take those `div`s and draw them on a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code to save image from canvas

function save_canvas_img()
            {

                var canvas = document.getElementById("your id");
                var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.open("POST",'save.php',false);
                ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/your page name');
                ajax.send(canvasData ); 

                alert('You have successfully saved this image');

            }`enter code here`
here save.php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{

    $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];


    $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
    // Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded

    //echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;
    $randomName = mktime(). rand(99999,9999999). '.png';



   $fp = fopen( 'foldername/'.$randomName, 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose( $fp );}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a 'screenshot' of your main div check out the links below

[Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156)

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/