# How to save the content of a div as an image?

Tags: php, html, image

I am using the code

```
<div style="background:url('upload/image1.jpg'); width:300px; height:400px; position:relative;">
    <br/>
    <div style="position: absolute; top:300px; overflow:hidden;  height:100px; width:300px;" id="overlay">This is a sample text</div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

In this i am using an image as the background of a div. And add an ovelay text to the image as in div overlay.

After adding the overlay text i want to save the main div as a new image. How to it ?

Comment: One way would be using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Comment: Already discussed in stackoverflow

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595541/capture-div-into-image-using-html2canvas

Comment: also discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252773/converting-contents-of-a-div-into-an-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would first need to use something like [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and then use javascript to save the canvas as an image with:

```
window.open(document.getElementById('canvas_id').toDataURL('image/png'));
```

this will render the html as an image, convert the image to a png data url, and then open that url in a new window, prompting a download of the image.